# How to de-duplicate notifications between native and progressive web app?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-push, push-api

If I have both a native app and a progressive web app using web push notifications powered by service worker, is there a way to prevent a user from receiving duplicate notifications if they opt in to receiving notifications from the web site and also have the app installed?

Answer (score 5):

In short - there is no easy way to do this today.

There is a discussion on Chrome here on this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402223

The last comment from October 2015:

> For now the safest minimal solution is for sites to provide an easy
>   opt out mechanism (which we strongly recommend you do anyway!) so
>   users can turn off notifications from one platform
>
> Another possible heuristic based solution is to take some measure for
>   which interface (web or native) the user most often uses (or most
>   recently used) and only send to that. Combined with grouping these
>   devices by rough screen size should give a pretty good approximation.
>
> The issue is that if the user has two similar sized devices and uses
>   native on one and web on the other then notifications will only be
>   delivered to one, which is an edge case.
>
> We've also been discussing building an API so sites can tell whether
>   their corresponding native app is installed to avoid this case, but
>   need to start discussing that with other browser vendors to see if
>   they'd be supportive.

Comment: Note there is now a small update in that issue that outlines a couple of additional techniques that can be used.